# siunitx error: "invalid-number" from R

Tags: siunitx, r, knitr

I have a document in `.Rnw` which I use to produce a `.tex`document with **kntir**. I have a problem with the formula `\num{\Sexpr{max(degree)}}` which in **R** console produce `12598` but after the running **knitr** in the **.tex** document becomes `\num{\ensuremath{1.2598\times 10^{4}}}`, which create the following error in **LaTex**:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! siunitx error: "invalid-number"
! 
! Invalid numerical input '\protect $\relax 1.2598\times 10^{4}$'.
! 
! See the siunitx documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.466 ... & \num{\ensuremath{1.2598\times 10^{4}}}
```

I am bit puzzled since in the document I have bigger numbers which do not create any problem when compiling.

These are my **/siunitx** options

```
%Separate digits with comma (e.g. 1,000,000)
\usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  detect-all,
  detect-inline-family=math,
  detect-inline-weight=math,
  detect-display-math=true}
```

Comment: Any chance of a MWE?

Comment: `\ensuremath` is problematic, `\times` probably too. Can't you configure R/knitr to output `\num{1.2598E4}` (or just `1.598E4` for a `S` column)?

Comment: Nope, no idea. Maybe it is easier to work on R to make sure the input is what I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to format the numbers using **siunitx**, while `knitr` also tries to do that automatically. Only one of them should be used, so either you do not use `\num{}`, or tell `knitr` to output the numbers without scientific notations (this is perhaps what you prefer), e.g. `\Sexpr{as.character(max(degree))}`, or use other functions like `format()`, `sprintf()`, and so on, to turn the numbers to character strings, so that `knitr` will no longer do scientific notations.

Comment: I don't mind let `knitr` manage the formatting of numbers. I just don't know how to set it to give me the comma (e.g. 10,000 instead of 10000)

Comment: I'd recommend you to use `siunitx` instead; it seems to be more powerful.

Comment: @Francesco I strongly recommend you let `siunitx` do all the formatting and try to get the most raw output from `knitr` you can get. `siunitx` has excellent capabilities in typesetting numbers and units and is very easy to configure (e.g. to get 10,000 instead of 10 000, just ask for `group-separator={,}`).

Comment: I think the `\num{\Sexpr{as.character(...)}}` approach is the most practical one. That is, to keep using `siunitx` while getting raw output from `knitr`.