# Knitr and numbers

Tags: math-mode, siunitx, r, knitr

I return to [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135758/siunitx-error-invalid-number-from-r), which is few months old and then maybe not yet the best practice around.

I use the `siunitx` package in my documents along with `knitr` to compile my R chunks. As far as I understand its behaviour, `knitr` will output integers treating them as normal characters while double into the `\ensuremath{}`environment.

Then

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Integer:
\Sexpr{14}

Double:
\Sexpr{-1.2324234}


\end{document}
```

will be knitted as

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Integer:
14

Double:
\ensuremath{-1.2324}


\end{document}
```

According to the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135837/27466) I got to my previous question (which is working) if I want to treat my numbers with `siunitx` and the `\num` environment I need to compile my doubles in my R chunks as characters, then `\Sexpr{as.character(-1.2324234)}` (or alternatively `\num{\Sexpr{as.character(-1.2324234)}}` if I want to leverage on `siunitx`) which will be knitted as `-1.2324234`. All good.

Yet I wonder if there's any better way to manage my output. First, sometime I am not sure whether my output will be an integer or a double; especially when my data change I might generate error throughout my code just because 1 turned 1.1. Second, the solution of wrapping everything around `as.character()` makes my code much heavier to read especially when I also wrap everything into `num{}`.

I then tried to `\renewcommand{\ensuremath}{\num}`, which was not the good idea I thought it was:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\ensuremath ->\num 

l.61 \ensuremath
                {-1.2324}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Is there any chance to gently ask `knitr` to output all numeric (integer and double) wrapped into `\num{}`?

Comment: I think you can copy `my_inline_hook <- knitr:::.inline.hook.tex`, modify it to suit your needs (you might need to add `knitr:::` in front of calls to internal `knitr` functions), and then use `knit_hooks$set(inline=my_inline_hook)` ?